# Сборка проекта Kotlin без сторонних систем сборки

Tags: kotlin, сборка

Интересуюсь про сборку проекта на Kotlin без использования сторонних систем.  На официальной страничке https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html смотрел, но это для простых, "однофайловых" программ. В книгах советуют ставить IntelliJ IDEA (а что же еще?))) и она все сделает за вас. Интересно разобраться про "ручную" сборку проекта Kotlin средствами самого Kotlin, с импортированием пакетов. Есть ли в Kotlin аналог ключа -sourcepath, как в Java? В kotlinc -help смотрел, вроде нет такого, может он по-другому называется?

Comment: Maven не поможет?

Comment: В том-то и вопрос. Везде сразу ссылки на Maven, Gradle и даже Ant. Должен же быть способ обычной сборки простейшего приложения в консоли?

Comment: А чем вам Maven не сборка в консоли? Ну может посмотреть какие команді вызывает maven и повторить их. Но зачем? Если вы начнете писать свои скрипты сборки, то на сложном проекте получите тот же maven

Comment: Хорошо, я перефразирую так - возможна ли сборка проекта на kotlin  средствами самого kotlin, а не с исполоьзованием сторонних продуктов типа Maven, Gradle, различных IDE и т.д.?

Comment: Я тоже смотрел, но пока нигде не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно указывать все файлы, которые хотите скомпилировать совместно:

A.kt:

```kotlin
fun f() {
    println("Hello")
}
```

B.kt:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    f()
}
```

Ну а затем:

```bsh
kotlinc A.kt B.kt -include-runtime -d AB.jar
java -jar AB.jar
```

Для всех остальных функций компилятора см. [документацию](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html).